Точка в предложении с дословным высказыванием при наличии сочинительных союзов
1.Ставится  точка в таком предложении:
Мы прочитали надписи: “Навек с тобой" и  “Здесь были Коля с Катей!” (.)
Сравнить с темой, где нет точки.
Можно ли оформить цитирование по правилам БСП, а не прямой речи при наличии двух отдельных цитат, связанных сочинительным союзом?  Тогда точка ставится.

Также меня интересует предложение с союзом ИЛИ из правил Розенталя, где точки нет: Не говорить же: Эй, собака!» или «Эй, кошка!» На этот единственный пример ориентированы все решения.

Оно оформлено по правилам обычной прямой речи (наличие ИЛИ не учитывается), точки в конце нет. Хотелось бы увидеть другие примеры с таким же оформлением. Может, здесь тоже нужно оформлять предложение как БСП с однородными членами?  Другой ж совсем синтаксис!

Мне кажется, что нужно поправить: Мы прочитали надписи...

Спасибо, исправила.
